# Sharepoint 2013 sweetalert2 ie doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint-framework

I was making a small notice board for users with sweetalert2. it is working well chrome. Testing with little script trigger button its working good chrome but still not showing ie.

I have to say my script working good index.html both browser, i am realy confused:)

here my code;

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteAssets/SweetAlert/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteAssets/SweetAlert/sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/SiteAssets/SweetAlert/promise-polyfill.js"></script>

  <script>

$( "#btn22" ).click(function() {
    debugger;
Swal(
'The Internet?',
'That thing is still around?',
'question'
)
console.log('tıklandı');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that SweetAlert2 does not and will not provide support or functionality of any kind on IE10 and lower.

Refer to this link: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2

[image]

By default, the SharePoint 2013 renders the content in IE10 mode defined in master page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

**Update:**

You can change it in the master page. But you need to note that the browser support in SharePoint 2013: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/browser-support-planning

As a workaround, you can force the specific page to use IE 11, you could create your own page file with HTML and load the page using `iframe`.

Here is a demo: https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/how-to-render-a-sharepoint-page-in-ie-using-edge-mode-without-changing-the-master-page/

Comment: thanks for comment, can i change that ?

Comment: You can change it in the master page. But you need to note that the browser support in SharePoint 2013: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/browser-support-planning  As a workaround, you can force the specific page to use IE 11, you could create your own page file with HTML and load the page using iframe.
Here is a demo: https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/how-to-render-a-sharepoint-page-in-ie-using-edge-mode-without-changing-the-master-page/